# Sharing an external hard drive in Ubuntu using Samba

Tags: ubuntu, samba, symbolic-link

`/media/MYDISK` is where my hard drive is mounted automatically. I created a symlink using:

```
ln -s /media/MYDISK /home/camilo/MYDISK
chmod 777 /home/camilo/MYDISK
```

I'm setting up smb.conf like this:

```
[myshare1]
comment = external disk
browsable = yes
path = /home/camilo/MYDISK
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0775
```

Also, in the `[global]` section I tried adding the following lines:

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
```

The problem is that when browsing the shared folder in Windows 7, I get a "\\etc\myshare1 is not accessible" error.
When pointing the `path` to a regular folder it works fine. Also, when I point it directly to `/media/MYDISK`, it shows the same error.

**EDIT**: to make it more interesting, I have no graphical interface, so I need to touch the config files directly..

Comment: Have you tried shares-admin? It comes with the system and works pretty well as far as writing the samba config.

Answer (score 10):

edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to include `force user = yourLogin` in the `[global]` section

from this thread, worked for me:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1710811

Comment: And restart service `service smbd restart`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) to configure your share. It will give you a web-based interface to which you can connect and easily configure many aspects of your server:

> What is Webmin?
>
> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix.
>   Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache,
>   DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually
>   edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a
>   system from the console or remotely. See the standard modules page for
>   a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the
>   screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I resolved it by mounting the external drive manually with my user (i.e. not root).

Answer (score 0):

The symlink:

ln -s /media/MYDISK /home/camilo/MYDISK

should already have 777 permissions, so no need for:

chmod 777 /home/camilo/MYDISK

although you may need to adjust the permissions of /media/MYDISK directly.

And in the samba share block directly use:

path = /media/MYDISK

instead of:

path = /home/camilo/MYDISK